# gnuplot data file with open or close parenthesis / parentheses "(" or ")" : "Skipping" warning / "x range is invalid"

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot, special-characters

I would like to read output from a `python` script that has parentheses and also commas (see below) directly into `gnuplot`. The error message is given below. Although it works, I would like to avoid pre-processing the output with the usual GNU/Linux tools (`sed,awk` etc.).

The output is from a `python` script (obtained on SO, link provided if needed) that is modified to make less editing. One example full line of the output is given below :

```
QuadraticBezier (106.774, 78.855)
```

There is a longer `.dat` file with similar lines that will plot nicely in `gnuplot` with this command (also obtained on SO - ask for link if needed):

```
plot "input.dat" using ($3):($2):2 w l, "input.dat" u 3:2
```

the `gnuplot` error message includes a `^` :

```
         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                                                                  ^
         x range is invalid
```

If I reduce the file down by hand - removing all `(`, `)`, and `,` to :

```
QuadraticBezier 106.774 78.855
```

the plot works (image provided if needed).

... otherwise I edit the `(` `)` out to avoid trouble in `gnuplot`. It seems the `,` is not the problem - and I am read `help datafile` section on `separator`, so I tried `set datafile separator "()"`, and the `using` section, and while `gnulplot` treats the characters *separating* the variables quite well, the case I describe above has special characters stuck onto the variables. I could continue pursuing this but it will help to know if this will not work, etc.

gnuplot version 5.4 patchlevel 2

Ubuntu Linux 22.04.2

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850680/how-to-extract-the-cartesian-coordinates-x-y-of-an-svg-image#65850680) showing a lot more about the `python` script output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following data format:

```
QuadraticBezier (106.774, 78.855)
```

and you want to extract and plot the two numbers, you need to define:

```
set datafile separator '(,)'
```

The closing parenthesis might be skipped.
If you don't separate at the comma, the second column will be interpreted as `106.774, 78.855` which leads to a floating point number of `106.774` and the 3rd column will be empty after the closing parenthesis.

**Script:**

```
### datafile separators
reset session

$Data <<EOD
QuadraticBezier (106.774, 78.855)
QuadraticBezier (222.222, 66.666)
QuadraticBezier (333.333, 55.555)
QuadraticBezier (444.444, 44.444)
EOD

set datafile separator "(,)"

plot $Data u 3:2 w lp pt 7
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]