# node.js and javascript library / script example : no output

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, command-line, nvm

I am trying to get the `javascript` code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850680/how-to-extract-the-cartesian-coordinates-x-y-of-an-svg-image) old post - converting SVG files to x,y coordinates in plain-text format - to work, and I am wondering what I am missing - it looks so simple. I put my setup and results below. I put the script here, with its notes from the original post :

"Write config.json with content e.g."

```
{
  "joinPathData": false,
  "minDistance": 0.5,
  "roundToNearest": 0.25,
  "sampleFrequency": 0.001,
  "pretty": false,
  "prettyIndent": 0
}
```

quoting : "In your code you may use library like this:"

```
import SVGPathInterpolator from 'SVGPathInterpolator';
const svgString = `
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
width="792px" height="612px" viewBox="0 0 792 612" enable-background="new 0 0 792 612" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path id="path3789" d="M287.168,442.411
        c-8.65,0-15.652,7.003-15.652,15.653
        c0,8.65,7.003,15.69,15.652,15.69
        s15.653-7.04,15.653-15.69
        "/>
    </g>
</svg>
`;
const config = {
    joinPathData: false,
    minDistance: 0.5,
    roundToNearest: 0.25,
    sampleFrequency: 0.001
};
const interpolator = new SVGPathInterpolator(config);
const pathData = interpolator.processSvg(svgString);
```

The following is beyond the scope, but important to note for troubleshooting : I used `apt` to install `npm` on this Ubuntu 22.04.2 Linux system. I installed SVGPathInterpolator library as described on the webpage - using `npm install -g svg-path-interpolator`. I also ran the local install `npm install svg-path-interpolator`, hoping it would just work. Instead of `svgpi`, which I found very little about, I got `node v19.7.0` by using `npm` and `nvm` as followed on the various webpages.

Back to the question : quoting the SO post : "Run it `svgpi config.json ballons.svg ballons.js"`.  (The file `balloons.svg` is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/wJHE5xcq)).

I execute in the `bash` shell `node config.json my_script_01.json balloons.svg output.js` and the process simply completes without any output or messages. In fact that is a new result - I only got this far just now - before, my setup produced errors such as `Unexpected token 'i', "import SVG"... is not valid JSON`. Perhaps I am on the right track - I am looking for ASCII plain-text x,y coordinates describing the vector shapes in the SVG file (see below).

I can see shell environment variables such as `NVM_INC` but I am not sure if that is relevant. Basic `javascript` examples work (e.g. from https://nodejs.dev/en/learn). More complex scripts do not and I think I am misunderstanding how to use the example script.

Is the `javascript` excerpt above expected to be built somehow into a bigger script e.g. a webpage - i.e. not run from the command line, but in a browser? I have seen how those example scripts work also so perhaps I can figure out how to make a webpage. The post describes a [website](https://spotify.github.io/coordinator/) which worked great at converting `svg` file vectors into `x,y` coordinates - thus, I expect the example script to do that - but I cannot understand how the script relates to that - I know I can read some website code using a browser, but I am not sure what to look for.

An update : I am trying to write a webpage to make this work, following [this](https://github.com/justinwilaby/svg-path-interpolator#readme).

As an aside : I asked about asking this question on Meta S.E. first, and am using the best guidance from [that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387131/is-it-ok-to-create-a-new-question-asking-about-code-in-an-old-answer-instead-of). Otherwise, I'd post a comment because my reputation is at 37 currently.

Comment: What do you expect an SVG construct to actually *do* when you run the code from the command line?

Comment: Ah, so I need to find a ```javascript``` command to write svg output - I have done that in ```python``` using ```matplotlib``` as ```plt.savefig```...

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what exactly you expect to happen when you issue a command in the form of `node config.json…`, and how you reached this conclusion (a source would be interesting to see)? What exactly do you believe Node should be doing with a JSON file which by definition wouldn’t contain executable JavaScript code?

Comment: @esqew I see - well, if I copy/paste the ```svg``` file into the website above, the output is ```x,y``` coordinates of the ```svg``` graphic elements... so a curve turns into dots. I could put a note in the question.

Comment: “*Instead of svgpi, which I found very little about, I got node v19.7.0*” How did you reach the conclusion that `node` (a full-out JavaScript interpreter) would be a direct 1:1 replacement for the `svgpi` binary program included in an NPM package?

Comment: @esqew ... I didn't know that. I _did_ find ```svgpi.mjs```, and have not learned what to do with that. Searching suggested that just trying ```node``` might work, as there is an error for the ```svg-path-interpolator``` package I did not share - ```npm WARN EBADENGINE    required: { node: '>=14.x'}```

Comment: I mis-wrote in the second comment above - the script is not expected to write SVG, but plain-text ASCII floating-point coordinates _of_ the SVG interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description in the quoted answer is somehow exact, but leaves out one detail that (I think) is irrelevant if you are on a Windows system. Installing the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-interpolator) globally with the `-g` flag

```
npm install -g svg-path-interpolator
```

may require administrative rights on a Debianoid system (which I infer from your `apt` reference). The main purpose is to make the script `svg-path-interpolator/bin/svgpi.mjs` available to all users as a global command `svgpi`. It seems this failed for you, the why being a question out of scope here. ([This](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/folders) might give you some hints.)

But you don't need the global command, you can execute the file directly with the node.js interpreter:

```
node path/to/svgpi.mjs config.json balloons.svg output.json
```

You could even leave out the call to node if you make sure you have the right to **execute** `svgpi.mjs`. (The first line of the script is a [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).)

```
path/to/svgpi.mjs config.json ballons.svg output.json
```

In the answer, the part starting with "In your code you may use" describes a *alternative* way to use the library. So you

- do **not** need a script like that if you want to convert from the command line. All you need is a `config.json`, an input `ballons.svg`, and an `output.json` will be written.
- do need the script if you want to integrate the conversion with other node.js tasks. Then the script as quoted replaces the input files, including their content inline as variables. The output also only appears as the value of a variable.

And before you are too suprised: the output is not in "plain-text format", but a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) file (or its object equivalent while still held in a variable).

Comment: I reorganized the working directory a bit - ensuring only the ```user``` has permission, and found the line ```await fs.mkdir(dir, {recursive: true});``` in ```svgpi.mjs``` produces an ```ENOENT``` error ```-2```. S.O. posts suggest ```recursive: true``` is correct . So I think that error originates from the ```svg-path-interpolator``` package. I should also note that the source post is over 2 years old. Perhaps the descriptions there only work with program versions from that time.

Comment: hang on... been meaning to manually adjust ```PATH```, so I did that, so the ```user``` installation is found. check with ```type svgpi.mjs```. Ran ```svgpi.mjs config.json balloons.svg``` - *without an output file* - as suggested in by the line ```if (outputFile)``` in ```svgpi.mjs``` works. Expected kinds of numbers (I hope what I need) go to ```stdout```. Did a ```> fubar.out```  now it seems have to convert that to some other format as needed (outside this Q/A). but this seems to work. Not perfect, needs work, but I'm calling this answered. Many thanks - hope this helps someone.

Comment: ... and I just discovered the ```ENOENT errno -2``` also happens if the input file is mistyped, or has a typo - e.g. ```balons.svg``` in this case.